# Passphrase Key-based authenication with net-sftp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, sftp, net-ssh, net-sftp

Based on question [Key based authenication with net-sftp in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1700882/850848), I can SFTP with key-based authentication using the following:

```
Net::SFTP.start(host, "user", keys:['~/.ssh/my_key']) do |sftp|
   sftp.upload! "/local/file.tgz", "/remote/file.tgz"
end
```

But I can't get this to work for keys that require a passphrase -- I just get prompted for the user login on that host. Am I missing something to pass in that would let me enter the passphrase for my key? Or do I need to just stick with `ssh-agent` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`passphrase` option](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/f54a2270dba3974081663b9780b493ed8d332a07/lib/net/ssh.rb#L168):

> the passphrase to use when loading a private key (default
> is `nil`, for no passphrase)

If you do not specify the `passphrase`, you should get asked for one, unless you used the `non_interactive` option:

> set to true if your app is non interactive and prefers
> authentication failure vs password prompt
>
> non interactive applications should set it to true
> to prefer failing a password/etc auth methods vs asking for password